# Why was it necessary to monitor the water quantity in the space shuttle?

Tags: space-shuttle, water

In [space shuttle's operators manual](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/johnson/pdf/390651main_shuttle_crew_operations_manual.pdf), Page(4.1-4), it is written as:

> The H<sub>2</sub>O quantity is determined by a PVT calculation based on H<sub>2</sub>O tank pressure and
> temperature transducer readings as well as GN2 tank pressure and temperature transducer
> readings. The calculated quantity is output to the HYD/APU display and to the SM SYS
> SUMM 2 and SPEC 86 APU/HYD displays
> [image]

Why was it necessary to measure water quantity? First and foremost, why was water necessary in the Space Shuttle? I am pretty sure that water was not for drinking purposes.  Perhaps for the purpose of cooling but not the engine.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Water was used for many purposes in the shuttle.

The particular application you are asking about is the Water Spray Boiler (WSB), part of the  Auxiliary Power Unit / Hydraulic (APU/Hyd) system. This device provided cooling to the lubrication oil in the APU and to the hydraulic fluid as required. Each of the three APU/Hyd systems had a dedicated WSB.

This cartoon shows the three operating modes of the WSB.

[image]

Here is an overall schematic of the WSB, from the document linked in the question.

[image]

For the spray mode, water was stored in a nitrogen-pressurized tank, shown at the upper left of the schematic. **This is the specific water you are asking about.** Knowing the quantity of water was necessary to manage the system.

Other uses of water in the shuttle:

- water cooling loops transferred heat from cabin equipment to Freon cooling loops
- injector cooling water for the APU
- Water was created as a byproduct of electrical power production - the O<sub>2</sub> / H<sub>2</sub> reaction in the fuel cells.  This water was consumed by the crew and used for cooling the Freon loops.

Source: former Systems instructor

Comment: Besides which, I would be surprised if there were any systems-level on-board resource that wasn't tracked somewhere. Perhaps not all mission resources (remaining paper towels - if such were on board) but anything at all related to the orbiter itself.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir agreed, all the uses of other water on the orbiter that I mention all had their quantities tracked, as did hundreds of other quantities. This answer was written to focus specifically on what was asked.